# How come I can write the first version but not the second?

Tags: haskell

We are trying to learn Haskell (for about the 5th time!) and still struggling with some basic issues.

So how come I can write

```
main = print (map (* 2) [1..5])
```

but I can't write

```
myfunc x =
   map ( (+ x) [1..5])

main = print (myfunc 2)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated --- we have the usual books but they're not really helping.

Comment: Why not? What is the compiler message?

Comment: What do you expect the expression `((+ x) [1..5])` to do?

Comment: I expect to call it in a function that passes in a value for x and returns a list of new values consisting of the original list with each item incremented by the value of x. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the basics.  The compiler messages have yet to make much sense to me although I'm certain they'll be more understandable as we learn more.

Comment: Functions in C/Java/similar languages have syntax like `function(arg1,arg2,arg3)`.  Haskell function syntax doesn't use the parentheses or the commas at all, their syntax is `function arg1 arg2 arg3`.  As the answers indicate, your parentheses are telling Haskell to apply `(+ x)` directly as a function, not send it as an argument to `map`.  If you review your type errors in this light, they may make more sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got the parentheses wrong.  You want:

```
myfunc x = map (+x) [1..5]
```

Answer (score 9):

In hopes of clearing up whatever misunderstanding prompted this: In Haskell, function application is *left-associative*, higher "precedence" than any infix operator, and does not require any parentheses. Parentheses are used only for grouping subexpressions: `(f x) y` is the same as just `f x y`, while `f (g x)` needs the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you...I even knew that fact but didn't apply it in this case.